# css in wordpress list

Tags: css, wordpress, list

cannot seem to get this bullet list to render properly. bullet points, numbers and titles are all fine - it seems to be the `<p class="pli">` that is not rendering as per its style; instead it appearing in bold and italic - which is not defined in the style sheet (below). I have put all the code and styles below, buggered if I know what is causing the issue??

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, causae tritani suscipit ex vis. His ad quodsi omnesque, in vel dolorum mentitum. Modus consul nostrum ut eos, probo vidisse at cum. Ei sed sonet laoreet comprehensam, vis ea viderer volumus sit.

<div id="boxd">
    <ol class="olol">
        <li class="olli"><span class="spand">1.</span>
            <p class="pli"><span class="ptitle">eam vivendum scriptorem eloquentiam ne</span>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, causae tritani suscipit ex vis. His ad quodsi omnesque, in vel dolorum mentitum. Modus consul nostrum ut eos, probo vidisse at cum. Ei sed sonet laoreet comprehensam, vis ea viderer volumus sit.</p>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>

############# css

#boxd {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.olol {
  color: #ccc;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.olli {
  position: relative;
  font: bold italic 45px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.pli {
  font: 12.5px/1.5 Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 60px;
  color: #555;
}
.spand {
  position: absolute;
  color: #cccccc;
}
.ptitle {
  color: #88D2DE;
  font: bold italic;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.subptitle {
  color: #0088dd;
  font: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: lorem ipsum what are you trying to say? flagged as spam

Comment: @m02ph3u5: Lorem Ipsum is common placeholder text (it is Latin but has similar properties to English text).

Comment: its not spam - for some reason my text got clipped off midway: my question should read:

cannot seem to get this bullet list to render properly. bullet points, numbers and titles are all fine - it seems to be the class=pli that is not rendering as per its style; instead it appearing in bold and italic - which is not defined in the style sheet (below). I have put all the code and styles below, buggered if I know what is causing the issue??? trying on a clean html page.

Comment: actually .ptitle is rendering in its defined css size and in bold.

Comment: For some reason the system won't let me edit your post to fix it - I recommend removing this question posting again. Make the code clearer by using the js/html/css snippet feature in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.pli {
  font: normal 12.5px/1.5 Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 60px;
  color: #555;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your list tag with class `.olli` contain a child which is a span tag. Hence the span tag contents inherited the font properties of its parent (`.olli`)

To illustrate this....look at the picture below for

```
<li class="olli"><span class="spand">2.</span>
```

[image]

I would suggest you to not style your `.olli` class tag for font and simply add your font styling to your `.spand` class tag (one possible solution)

snippet